# Counter-Example

Tags: algebra-precalculus, infinity

This question is a true and false question.

> A rational function can have infinitely many x-values at which it is not continuous.

The textbook has the answer as:

> **false**, because a rational function can be written as $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $P$ and Q are polynomials of degree m and n, respectively.  It can at most have $n$ discontinuities.

I thought it could be

> **true**, because I can write it as 
>   $$\frac{x}{(x-\infty)...(x-1)(x)(x+1)...(x+\infty)}$$

Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Your denominator $Q(x)$ is not a function, and certainly not a polynomial of degree $n$

Comment: Polynomials, by definition, have finite degree.

Comment: Furthermore, it is incorrect to think of $\infty$ as a *number* (and so you cannot treat as such, like in $(x + \infty)$), when it is more a concept of *size* (cardinality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x-\infty)\ldots(x-1)(x)(x+1)\ldots(x+\infty)$$
is not a meaningfull expression.
There is no  number $\infty$.
The expression
$$\cdots(x-1)(x)(x+1)\cdots$$
isn't meaningfull, too.

There are functions that have a zero at any $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ but these functions are not polynomials.

A polynomial has only finitely many zeroes. So you are wrong and the book is right.